# Why Redux reducer returns undefined after action click?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-table

I have a `React-table` in which I pass data from reducer's `initialState` like this:

```
const getData = () => {
    return {
        data: [{},{},{}]
    }
}

const initialState = getData();

const ipReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    if (action.type === 'CHANGE_IP_STATUS') {
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
        return { newState }

    } else {
        return state;
    }
}

export default ipReducer;
```

`getData()` will get data from server.

And I have switchers in table rows which can change the table data state. So I perform a redux action to change the state of a table. But when the action is done the table table gets `undefined` data.

This is my table:

```
<div>
     <ReactTable
         data={this.props.data}
         columns={columns}
     />
</div>
```

And this is my state to props map:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.ipTable.data,
})
```

From `console.log()` I see that my `ipReducer` returns valid data object. But why this object doesn't appears in my table component after change state perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `return { newState }` you should just return `newState` since its already an object created from updated state

```
const ipReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    if (action.type === 'CHANGE_IP_STATUS') {
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
        return newState;

    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
```